# WordPress can't dequeue style

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get rid of unused styles in my WP. I'm doing it like this:

```
// remove CSS
add_action('wp_dequeue_style', 'remove_css');

function remove_css() {
    // boostrap shortcodes
    wp_dequeue_style(array(
        'bs_bootstrap-css',
        'bs_shortcodes-css'
    ));

    // woocommerce
    wp_dequeue_style('woocommerce-layout-css');
    wp_dequeue_style('woocommerce-smallscreen-css');
    wp_dequeue_style('woocommerce-general-css');
}
```

Problem is, neither first nor the secound example works. I tried using `wp_deregister_script` and setting a priority to `add_action`. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so26892641_remove_css', 25 );
function so26892641_remove_css(){
    wp_dequeue_style('woocommerce-layout');
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Fun fact: when I removed `-css`, like @Anand suggested, it worked.

Comment: True indeed, WP adds `-css` and `-js` to the handles for styles and scripts respectively.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `wp_dequeue_style` (y)

Answer (score 2):

Woocommerce has a filter for that, also note that the handles do not have "-css" at the end.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'jk_dequeue_styles' );

function jk_dequeue_styles( $enqueue_styles ) {
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-general'] ); // Remove the gloss
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-layout'] ); // Remove the layout
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-smallscreen'] ); // Remove the smallscreen optimisation
    return $enqueue_styles;
}
```

Code shamelessly copied from the following [link](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/) :)